# PLSQL How to generate a query with a indicative

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a oracle script that for easy use have a variable. right now iám using PLSQL Developer, By allroundautomations.

Each time i execute this query, it ask me to introduce a input, wich makes everything easier.

In this particular case, the input data must have a indicative ('508'), and i need the variable that ask me the input data have preintroduced this indicative ('508').

This is the query i used with a variable.

```
select * from TABLE where FIELD = ('&VARIABLE');
```

When the query is executed the program shows a pop up asking me the input data.

How could i get this done???, when it ask me the input data, the pop up have preentered the value 508.

thank you.

EDIT

I have finally resolved this issue, the sql script looks like this:

select * from TABLE where FIELD = ('508' || &VARIABLE);

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click inside your sql window and select "Change Window to:  test Window
- change your script to

  select * from TABLE where FIELD = (:YourVARIABLE);
- a new box opens at the bottom
- Under the Variable column enter YourVariable
- Under the Type enter String
- Under value enter 508
- Press F8 to execute